# Graph two interpolations together

Tags: graphics, interpolation

I have created two functions, `inter1=Interpolation[points1]` and `inter2=Interpolation[points2]`.
This creates two functions, I then created a graph `Manipulate[ListLinePlot[inter1, InterpolationOrder -> n],{n, 0, 6, 1}]`. However I need to combine these functions together. I want to be able to graph each function together and manipulate each function separately based on `InterpolationOrder`. Can someone please help?

This is how far I've come

```
points = {{1,79},{2,181},{3,181},{4,52},{5,49},{6,8},{7,137},{8,79},{9,112},{10,164}};
inter1 = Interpolation[points];
inter2 = Interpolation[points];
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[inter1, InterpolationOrder -> n], {n,0,6,1}]
```

Regards

New to Mathematica

Comment: Could you add a minimal complete example ?

Comment: Ive added what ive done so fare, I just want does functions together and be able to manipulate InterpolationOrder of each function by itself.

Comment: in the code you posted, where's the diff between `inter1` and `inter2`?

Comment: Use two ListLinePlots and combine them using `Show`

Comment: There is no difference between inter1 and inter 2. I just want to be able to manipulate the difference in the graph based on interpolation order of each function. Would you be able to show a more specific answere then combining them with Show? Ive just started using mathematica and I dont know how this is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the data you provide overlap I created some variation:

```
points = {{1, 79}, {2, 181}, {3, 181}, {4, 52}, {5, 49}, {6, 8}, {7, 
    137}, {8, 79}, {9, 112}, {10, 164}};
inter1 = Interpolation[points];
inter2 = Interpolation[
   points + 
    Transpose[{ConstantArray[0, {Length[points]}], 
      RandomInteger[{-15, 15}, {Length[points]}]}]];
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[{inter1, inter2}, InterpolationOrder -> n], {n, 0, 6, 
  1}]
```

[image]

Perhaps you are looking for the difference in quality of various interpolation orders:

```
points = {{1, 79}, {2, 181}, {3, 181}, {4, 52}, {5, 49}, {6, 8}, {7, 
    137}, {8, 79}, {9, 112}, {10, 164}};
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[
   Interpolation[points, InterpolationOrder -> n1][t] - 
    Interpolation[points, InterpolationOrder -> n2][t]], {t, 
   Min[points[[All, 1]]], Max[points[[All, 1]]]}], {n1, 0, 6, 1}, {n2,
   0, 6, 1}]
```

[image]

Yet another alternative:

```
points = {{1, 79}, {2, 181}, {3, 181}, {4, 52}, {5, 49}, {6, 8}, {7, 
    137}, {8, 79}, {9, 112}, {10, 164}};
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[{Interpolation[points, InterpolationOrder -> n1][t], 
    Interpolation[points, InterpolationOrder -> n2][t]}], {t, 
   Min[points[[All, 1]]], Max[points[[All, 1]]]}], {n1, 0, 6, 1}, {n2,
   0, 6, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, I don`t think I am explaining my self well, in this case you have made two different functions because the data overlap. I want the data to overlap, because its the same function, but when I change the Interpolation order(n) to 6 on one function(inter1) and interpolation order (n) to 1 on one function(inter2) then i would be able to see the difference.

Comment: @ALEXANDER, see the edit. Does that help?

Comment: I don´t know how to explain it, this is all great but I need to functions on top of each other initially. Then when i change one function based on its interpolation order i get one line which is different from the second line. The example shown above i dont understand, because I want two lines and be able to manipulate the interpolation order by itself for each line.

Comment: @ALEXANDER, how about that one.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I am looking for! Amazing that people like you are willing to spend there time helping other people with sharing there knowledge! Only hope that one day Ill be good enough to help people with mathematica! Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @ALEXANDER, most welcome ;-) I like to share my passing for Mathematica. I remember very well when I started using it and did not "get" it. I did not like using Mathematica at all, but slowly I realized to someone had put quite a lot of thought into it. Mathematica's consistency and the benefits of that are amazing. In fact I liked it so much that I started consulting WRI...that's a long story put very short.

Comment: @ALEXANDER Don't forget to upvote Ruebenko's answer if it helps you!

Comment: Thank you! How do i upvote and give credit for the help?

Comment: @ALEXANDER, there are up and down pointing gray triangles. Also see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hi! Ruebenko, I think Ive done it correctly rating it. I have one more question, [points, InterpolationOrder -> n2][t] - What is really going on, when you have ..... n2][t] Square brackets is as fare as I know for functions, however here you have to functions with no comma or anything separating them and I don´t understand what is actually happening behind? could you explain what is going on behind? Thank you!

Comment: @ALEXANDER, look at this example: `myFun1 = Function[x, Function[t, x + t]]` this is a function returning a function. `g=myFun1[2]` returns a new function with `x==2`. You can use `g[10]` or directly
`myFun1[2][10]`.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, here's the `Show` approach that was suggested:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ListLinePlot[inter1,
   PlotStyle -> Red,
   PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Opacity[0.25], Disk[]}], .025},
   PlotRange -> All,
   InterpolationOrder -> order1],
  ListLinePlot[inter2,
   PlotStyle -> Blue,
   InterpolationOrder -> order2]
  ],
 {order1, 0, 6, 1},
 {order2, 0, 6, 1}]
```

[image: show]